# jQuery+ajax jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm making a $.ajax async:false response to a localhost server but I have this error:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8001/academialopedevega/get/get_alumnos_leen_novedades.php?idAlumno=10&idAsignatura=1. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

When I paste the URL in a new tab it works fine and return the json.

This is the javascript code:

```
function novedades(){
$("#contenido").empty();

console.log( url );
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.success==0){
            $("#contenido").append('<p>Aun no te has matriculado en ninguna asignatura.</p>');
        }else{
            $("#contenido").append('<ul id="asignaturas" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-theme="d">');


        }
    });

        var url="http://192.168.1.108:8001/academialopedevega/get/get_oferta_usuario.php?idUsuario="+localStorage.getItem('idConectado');
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.asignatura,function(a,b){
                console.log(b);
                idA = b.idA;
                nombreA = b.nombre;
                horasA = b.horas;
                tipoA = b.tipo;

                url2='http://localhost:8001/academialopedevega/get/get_alumnos_leen_novedades.php?idAlumno='+localStorage.getItem('idConectado')+'&idAsignatura='+idA;
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url2,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data2) {
                        $.each(data2,function(c,d){
                            cuenta=d.cuenta;

                            $("#asignaturas").append('<li class="botonMenu titulos"><a href="#">'+nombreA+'<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">'+cuenta+'</span></a></li></ul>');
                            $("#contenido").append("</ul>");
                            $("#asignaturas").listview();
                            $("#asignaturas").listview('refresh'); 
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });


    $("#mipanel").panel("close");
   }
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$respuesta=array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

//Recibe los parametros:
/*
$alumnos_id = El id del usuario
$asignaturas_id = El id de la asignatura
$nota = La nota del alumno
*/

if(isset($_GET['idUsuario'])){
$idUsuario=$_GET['idUsuario'];


//Query para insertar

        $resultado_asignaturas=mysql_query('select * from asignaturas inner join oferta_educativa_tiene_asignaturas on oferta_educativa_tiene_asignaturas.asignaturas_id=asignaturas.id inner join oferta_educativa_tiene_alumnos on oferta_educativa_tiene_alumnos.oferta_educativa_tiene_asignaturas_asignaturas_id=oferta_educativa_tiene_asignaturas.asignaturas_id where oferta_educativa_tiene_alumnos.alumnos_usuarios_id='.$idUsuario.' group by id');
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultado_asignaturas) > 0) {

            $respuesta['asignatura'] = array();

            while ($fila_oferta = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_asignaturas)) {

            //Anuncio
            $idA = $fila_oferta['id'];
            $nombreA = $fila_oferta["nombre"];
            $horasA = $fila_oferta["horas"];
            $tipoA = $fila_oferta["tipo"];
            $cursoA = $fila_oferta["curso"];

            $asignatura = array('idA' => $idA, 'nombre' => $nombreA, 'horas' => $horasA, 'tipo' => $tipoA, 'curso' => $cursoA);

            array_push($respuesta["asignatura"], $asignatura);
        }
// success
$respuesta["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($respuesta);
}else{
    // no hay
    $respuesta["success"] = 0;
    $respuesta["message"] = "No se ha encontrado nada :(";

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
}
else{
    echo 'Introduce los campos';
}

?>
```

If I use other version of jQuery the jQuerymobile dont works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your request URL. Does it in the same domain with your browser?
You can choose one domain from `192.168.1.108:8001` and `localhost:8001` to use, but do not mix use.

Comment: Hi, I use localhost:8000 trying options, firstly I have 192.168.1.108 in both of URLS. It dont work

Comment: Okay, It works! lots of thanks, I tryed it before but I think I try with the two localhost not 192.168.1.108.