# IIS Server Gets Stuck for few seconds in recursion Function

Tags: javascript, flask, iis

I'm calling an Flask API using ajax by recursion function.
For most of the time its working fine. But its getting stuck after around a minute.
[image]

All the Above Api took only 60-70 mili seconds. But this last api took 10.24 seconds to complete

[image]

Because of this my whole camera app look Stutter.

At first I thought it was getting stuck due to code. But I have tested with the time difference inside code and it stays at 60-70 milliseconds for all APIs.

[image: Time difference on every section of code]

So before Hitting my API code its getting stuck sometimes. I believe its because of IIS Server is not hitting my flask API in time.

Here's my config for IIS Server

[image]
[image]

Config File-
*C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config*

```
</fastCgi>
...

<application fullPath="D:\aiml_python_code\yolov7-main\venv37\Scripts\python.exe" arguments="D:\aiml_python_code\yolov7-main\venv37\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" monitorChangesTo="" stderrMode="ReturnStdErrIn500" maxInstances="400" idleTimeout="2592000" activityTimeout="3000" requestTimeout="900000" instanceMaxRequests="200000" signalBeforeTerminateSeconds="0" protocol="NamedPipe" queueLength="100000" flushNamedPipe="false" rapidFailsPerMinute="1000" />
 </fastCgi>
```

Edit-

Here's my JavaScript recursion function

```
function api_Call() {

    cameraSensor.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
    cameraSensor.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
    cameraSensor.getContext("2d").drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);

    let c = document.getElementById("cam_frame");
    c.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
    c.height = cameraView.videoHeight;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        dataType: "json",
        <!-- timeout: 1000, -->
        data: JSON.stringify({'image':cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/webp")}),
        url: "/flaskapi3/imagepred",
        success: function (response) {
            data = response['data'];
            c.src = "data:image/png;base64, "+data;
            api_Call();
      },
        error: function (err) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                api_Call();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    };
```

Comment: So it is getting stuck after around a minute and not giving any error message? Or it gets back to work after getting stuck for a few seconds? According to recursion function code, I think it is due to IIS unable to load a jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5. The setTimeout() parameter continues to call the api_Call function causing it get stuck. Without detailed error information, it is difficult to locate the reason why IIS cannot load the API.

Comment: I have an idea, you can try to comment out error: function and run. See if you can get some error messages. Just like the error in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604617/jqueryajax-jquery-1-11-3-min-js5-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load). Or you can use FRT(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing) to generate logs. They can all help you better locate the cause.

Comment: @TengFeiXie I'm not getting any error Since you can see in above screenshot, api is getting called after 10 seconds. Where as rest of the api took 60-70ms. There is no failed request. This delay is causing stutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the config in IIS FastAPI App. MaxRequests default is set to 200. We have to change it to its maximum

1. Go to FastAPI app.
   [image]
2. Select your App and change `Instance MaxRequests` from 200 to its Maximum value.
   [image]